# How to get featured image of last post in a category?

Tags: images, categories

I have the following code and want to add a selected featured image

```
    $arg = array(
       'orderby'    => 'date',
       'number'     => 10,
    );
    $categories = get_categories($arg);
    foreach ($categories as $cat) {
         echo '<li>';
         echo '<figure>
                <a href="?catId='.$cat->cat_ID.'">';
                   //Add featured image from the last post??
                    get_last_post_image($cat->name);
        echo '</a>
             </figure>';
         </li>';
      }
```

And I have this function:

```
function get_last_post_image($cat_name){
    $args = array(
        'category_name' => '$cat_name',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'order_by' => 'date',
        'order' => 'desc'
    );
    $post = get_posts( $args );
    if($post) {
        $post_id = $post[0]->ID;
        if(has_post_thumbnail($post_id)){
            echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail');
        }
    }
}
```

But the featured image is never displayed.

Comment: "Title Background Image" is not a field created by WordPress Core - it's being added through either a plugin or your theme. You'll want to search through them to find out what plugin or theme is adding it, and then you can use their support channels or browse through their code to find out how they are saving it and how to retrieve it. :)

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question consequently...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct this line in your code at the end of function.

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail');
```

should be

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'thumbnail');
```

also as per Wordpress [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters), `category_name` parameter should be a string representing category `slug`, not `name`.

So, the complete code should look like this:

```
    $arg = array(
       'orderby'    => 'date',
       'number'     => 10,
    );
    $categories = get_categories($arg);
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ($categories as $cat) {
         echo '<li>';
         echo '<figure>
                <a href="?catId='.$cat->term_id.'">'; // not cat_ID
                   //Add featured image from the last post??
                    get_last_post_image($cat->slug);
        echo '</a>
             </figure>
         </li>';
      } 
    echo '</ul>';
```

And the function:

```
function get_last_post_image($cat_slug){
    $args = array(
        'category_name' => $cat_slug, // it should be slug of category, not name.
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'order_by' => 'date',
        'order' => 'desc'
    );
    $post = get_posts( $args );
    if($post) {
        $post_id = $post[0]->ID;
        if(has_post_thumbnail($post_id)){
            echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'thumbnail');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I still have a problem with `if($post){...}`as `if($post) {
...}else{echo "Error";}` gives "Error"

Comment: Because no posts are returned by `get_post()`. As per Wordpress, `category_name` parameter should be a string representing category `slug`, not `name`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: thanks, it works but it only displays the last post thumbnail (and not last post per category).

Comment: You mean same image (thumbnail of latest blog post) is repeated for each category?

Comment: Yes, last post thumbnail is repeated no matter which category it is. https://imgur.com/Nax8REu

Comment: You might be missing something from my answer,  it works fine on my setup. Please compare your code with updated answer.